# How to get all the tuple pairs in a list with the min value among the first element

Tags: list, min

The output would only be the first instance in the list, whereas I want to have both instances of [(1,'a'),(1,'b')]

```
smallest_teams = []

roster = [(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(3,'c')]

smallest_teams = list(min(roster))
print(smallest_teams)
```

The output would only be the first instance in the list, whereas I want to have both instances of [(1,'a'),(1,'b')]

```
smallest_teams = []

roster = [(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(3,'c')]

smallest_teams = list(min(roster))
print(smallest_teams)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result using a for loop. You can keep track of the smallest teams in list as you go and reset the list as soon as you come across a smaller value

```py
roster = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
min_value = float('inf')  # Initialize min_value to positive infinity
smallest_teams = []

for item in roster:
    if item[0] < min_value:
        min_value = item[0]
        smallest_teams = [item]
    elif item[0] == min_value:
        smallest_teams.append(item)

print(smallest_teams)
```